# How to apply script with onEdit() trigger for another Google spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet with an example script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  console.log(e.value)
}
```

I saved this version as `Test1`

[image: Test1]

Then I created a new spreadsheet in my Google Drive and connected my script with a library

[image]

So how can I apply my script for the new spreadsheet?
It should works absolutely same as my source script.

Comment: Not possible...

Comment: @TheMaster Maybe you know some another way?

Comment: AFAIK, Publishing a addon is the only way for scripts that need authorization. If it's just a simple trigger, you might get away with writing the script to all your sheets programmatically through [tag:google-apps-script-api]